# Detached state в hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java

Добрый день!
В гибернейт определено состояние detached, что означает сессия завершилась. И теперь для сохранения сущности в БД, необходимо сессию открыть и закомитить изменения.
Зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с объектом вне сессии, например, на клиенте.